# Android launcher - browser link redirect shortcut

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons, android-shortcut, android-shortcutmanager

**Hello!**

I want to add an Android launcher shortcut to open a link with it. Something like this images
This is possible? And if is possible, how can I make it?

[image: enter images description here]

Comment: They are called [App shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)

Comment: I know this but idk how to add link shortcut XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An example of creating a dynamic shortcut and associating it with your
> app appears in the following code snippet:

```
ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, "id1")
    .setShortLabel("Website")
    .setLongLabel("Open the website")
    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.icon_website))
    .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                   Uri.parse("https://www.mysite.example.com/")))
    .build();

ShortcutManagerCompat.pushDynamicShortcut(context, shortcut);
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#dynamic)